# SQL- The Decode Function greater than

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying the decode function but I can't get it work - please help.

```
select 
    naam, maandsal*2, mnr,
    DECODE(maandsal * 2 > mnr, maandsal * 2),
    DECODE(mnr > maandsal , mnr) 
from 
    medewerkers;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use an out-of-date Oracle function in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
select naam, maandsal2, mnr, 
       (case when maandsal2 > mnr then maandsal*2 end),
       (case when mnr > maandsal then mnr end)
from medewerkers;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked: select naam,maandsal*2,mnr,
  2  (case when maandsal*2> mnr then maandsal*2 end),
  3  (case when mnr > maandsal*2 then mnr end) from medewerkers;